# Carousel slider with description below changing

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, slider, carousel, paint

I`m working on a website for my paintings with a carousel and description of a painting below. I would like the description below the carousel to change with each painting whenever I click on the arrows of the carousel.

Here`s the code: https://mirek88.github.io/paintings/index-2.html

I would really appreciate any help. 
Thanks!
Mirek

Comment: Is the description longer than what the carousel-caption can take ?

Comment: i am afraid so - in some cases more than 15 lines.

Comment: @SearchingThe idea is for the visitor to see the image without any text and when he scrolls down, the detailed description of the painting.

Comment: I tried to add some javascript but don`t know how to get it running properly: https://mirek88.github.io/paintings/index-3.html

Comment: SO doesn't encourage providing code,but you are on the right path. Try implementing this option. Listen on events from the carousel, use data-attributes on the carousel slide to mark which description `div`  e.g `data-desc="slide-1"` relates to `div id="slide-1"` description content. when slide has completed you can get the active slide, get the data-attribute and then use jquery to show/hide the description div. https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/#events . let us know if you get stuck by updating the question with code.